# How to refresh <iframe> using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I would like to refresh this link `http://radiojoven.6te.net/capas.php` using AJAX. I've been trying, but to no avail. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script>
function checkRequest() {
    var interval = setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://radiojoven.6te.net/capas.php",
            type: "post",
            datatype: "html"
        })
            .done(function (msg) {
            $("capas").html(msg);
        })
            .always(function () {
            checkRequest();
        });
    }, 20000);
}
</script>
```

The iframe I plan update:

```
<div id="capas"><iframe src="http://radiojoven.6te.net/capas.php"
     width="1000px" height="300px" border="0" marginwidth="0"
     marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

If anyone can help me in this work, I would be very grateful.

Already thank you.

Comment: `$("capas").html(msg);` it's missing the `#` symbol `$("#capas").html(msg);`. The `#` is for "id". check your console.

Comment: If the content is in an iframe, why bother with AJAX? You can just `reload()` the frame.

Comment: ...or `.load()` http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to get rid of the `iframe` all together and just use `AJAX`.

The reason why it never updates is that the `capas` div is not referenced correctly.

You need `$("#capas").html(msg);` // Note the # to refer to the ID of the element.

As an additional note, it doesn't seem you are posting any data to the server, therefore you may be better of using a `HTTP GET` rather than a `HTTP POST`.

Comment: [Yeah, I said that...5 mins. prior to this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242788/how-to-refresh-iframe-using-ajax#comment58199442_35242788). Had I known...

Comment: @Fred-ii- - that's great, you should have posted it as an answer.  I have also included some additional recommendations in mine.

Comment: I didn't bother to post it as an answer, because it's a typo (I voted to close the question as such) and I don't post answers 99% of the time when they are (typos), only if the OP specifically asks me to, in this case they most probably won't; they hardly ever do ;-)

Comment: @Darren Davies I've been to analyze the answers and thank you in advance to everyone, even changing the code with $ ( "# covers") html (msg).; it does not update the iframe me if I wanted to update the case with AJAX you had to do?

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this. Note that I changed your `iframe` for a `div`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Ajax(){
var xmlHttp;
    try{    
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e){
            try{
                    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
                   }
            catch (e){
                try{
                            xmlHttp=newActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e){
                            alert("No AJAX!?");
                            return false;
                    }
            }
    }

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById('capas').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            setTimeout('Ajax()',10);
    }
 }
            xmlHttp.open("GET","http://radiojoven.6te.net/capas.php",true); 
     // aqui configuramos o arquivo
     xmlHttp.send(null);
 }

     window.onload=function(){
          setTimeout('Ajax()',10); 
       // aqui o tempo entre uma atualização e outra
     }
     </script>

     <div id="capas"></div>
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.